# Contact Selector

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, contactscontract

I've been working on this single function for my intro to Comp Eng Mobile App Class, for about a week, starting to understand Cursors, contentresolvers, and adapters.  But the code, recognizes I never use a cursor, but I don't know how to incorporate cursor into this program.

```
public class HelloAutoCompleteActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ContentResolver content = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = content.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, PEOPLE_PROJECTION, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
//      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, PEOPLE_PROJECTION);
//      textView.ContactListAdapter adapter = new textView.ContactListAdapter(this, cursor);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private static final String[] PEOPLE_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._COUNT,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
         };

    //Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
    Uri contacts =  ContactsContract.AUTHORITY_URI;

    ////Make the query. 
    Cursor cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you started understanding the Cursor, so since you are aware of basic function of the cursor, it used to hold the data returned by the Query on the database. since in the above code you are querying the Contact database of the device. and the code returns data in the cursor, since you are not using that further. you can use cursor and do below

1. take contact name and display on the screen
2. take contact name and number and display.

Below is the link for the sample program, import it you will get better idea.

http://l8rs.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-sample-list-contact-book-and.html